# Слайд определенного размера в slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slick.js

Использую `slick slider`. Возникла проблема,-  нужно сделать отступы между слайдами и сделать слайдам ограничение по ширине, например: `max-width: 370px;`, как в моем случае. Проблема заключается в том, что когда слайдам применяешь такую настройку как, `max-width`, то слайдер ломается, появляется часть следующего слайдера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, как сделать что бы можно было применять определенную ширину для слайда и делать отступы между слайдами?

```js
$('.slide_wrapper').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slides {
  msx-width: 200px;
  
}

.slides_1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.slides_2 {
  backgound-color: red;
  
}
.slides_3 {
  backgorund-color: red;
}

.slides_4 {
  backgound-color: red;
}

.slides_5 {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slide_wrapper">
      <div class="slides slides_1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?
      </div>
      <div class="slides slides_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?</div>
      <div class="slides slides_3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?</div>
      <div class="slides slides_4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?</div>
      <div class="slides slides_5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте чистую обертку для каждого слайда. А уже внутри обертки манипулируйте своими слайдами как хотите

```js
$('.slide_wrapper').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slides {
  max-width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slides_1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.slides_2 {
  backgound-color: red;
  
}
.slides_3 {
  backgorund-color: red;
}

.slides_4 {
  backgound-color: red;
}

.slides_5 {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slide_wrapper">
      <div> <!-- Оборачиваем каждый слайд в чистый div -->
        <div class="slides slides_1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div> <!-- Оборачиваем каждый слайд в чистый div -->
        <div class="slides slides_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div> <!-- Оборачиваем каждый слайд в чистый div -->
        <div class="slides slides_3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div> <!-- Оборачиваем каждый слайд в чистый div -->
        <div class="slides slides_4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div> <!-- Оборачиваем каждый слайд в чистый div -->
        <div class="slides slides_5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</body>
```