# Slick-slider обрезает ширину изображения

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Со slick работаю уже 4-ый проект, и подобное - впервые.

Проблема: слайдер обрезает изображение, вместо слайда, растянутого по ширине экрана (container-fluid), слайд обрезается до значения в 1520px.

Должно быть вот так:

[image: Должно быть]

А по факту, при подключении слайдера работает вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('.slick__slider').slick({

});
```

```css
.slider {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;


    .slider__item {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
        background-position: center top;
        zoom: .8;
        z-index: 1;
        
        .slider__item-info {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 999;

            h1 {
                font-family: Roboto;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            p {
                font-family: Roboto;
                font-weight: lighter;
                color: #000;
                font-size: 1.5rem;
            }
        }
    }

    .slider__item:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: $border__color;
        opacity: .3;
        z-index: 2;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>



<section class="container-fluid slider slick__slider">
    <div class="slider__item" style="background-image: url(http://expnk.ru/slider.png); width: 100%;">
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="slider__item-info">
                <h1>Счастливые часы</h1>
                <p>скидка 10% для всех пациентов в период с 23.11.2019 по 31.11.2019г!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item" style="background-image: url(http://expnk.ru/slider.png); width: 100%;">
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="slider__item-info">
                <h1>Счастливые часы</h1>
                <p>скидка 10% для всех пациентов в период с 23.11.2019 по 31.11.2019г!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item" style="background-image: url(http://expnk.ru/slider.png); width: 100%;">
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="slider__item-info">
                <h1>Счастливые часы</h1>
                <p>скидка 10% для всех пациентов в период с 23.11.2019 по 31.11.2019г!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817523/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-slick-slider/817592#817592

Comment: @l2banners благодарю!